# vagrant : how to get hostonly ip address from within chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to retrieve the hostonly ip address specified in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.33"
```

in a recipe file :

**mycookbook/files/default/xdebug.ini**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "***HERE***"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:eth1][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
```

Actually you can find out all the node attributes by logging into the VM (with **vagrant ssh**) and running shef. And inspect there the node object.

Comment: thank you for your advice, however, I get an error when trying to use shef:
chef > nodes.all
[2013-01-28T11:22:43+01:00] WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /etc/chef/client.pem>
Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.16.2/lib/chef/rest/auth_credentials.rb:64:i

Comment: Well, I think I got the reason... Chef-Solo does not provide that kind of information.

Comment: No, it is not related to using chef_client or chef_solo. Have you logged into vagrant VM before running shef? If yes, then your shef is somehow configured by default to run in chef_client mode. You can switch to solo mode by running `shef -s`. Then it will not ask you for any keys and will allow you to inspect the local node.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I still get that error running shef -s:
chef > nodes.all
[2013-01-28T13:43:26+01:00] WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /etc/chef/client.pem>
same for environments etc.

Comment: Because `nodes.all` uses search, which is available only for chef-client. But nothing prevents you from inspecting local node by: `node[:network]`... and so on.

Comment: Ok, all of this is a bit confusing, I guess I have to find a dictionary with all the available nodes now :)

Comment: Can you explain the .detect method you are using? is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It's a Enumerable#detect method in Ruby.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect

Comment: This assumes the default network is eth1.  A more robust solution would be:

**node[:network][:interfaces][node[:network][:default_interface]][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first**

However, I have used this **node[:ipaddress]** with success, though I may have just been lucky!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the IP of the Host machine, you can use this:

in your recipe:

**your/cookbook/path/recipes/default.rb**

```
ip = node[:network][:interfaces][:eth1][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
remote_ip = ip.gsub /\.\d+$/, '.1'

template "/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini" do
  source "xdebug.ini.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
  variables({
              "remote_host" => remote_ip
            })
end
```

and in the template:
**your/cookbook/path/templates/default/xdebug.ini.erb**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = <%= @remote_host %>
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the json output of **ohai** and looking for what had shown in the initial **vagrant ssh** login output, right before the prompt:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Tue Sep 29 13:40:10 2015 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@vagrant:~$
```

In the ohai output I found 10.0.2.2 among other locations in

```
[:network][:default_gateway]
```

I confirmed that by starting **shef** in ssh, as per Draco's info

```
chef >     node[:network][:default_gateway]
 => "10.0.2.2"
```

That worked for me and I could curl manually in bash against the python SimpleHTTPServer I had set up on the host.  Next is using this in chef proper.

This is my network entry in the Vagrantfile, just in case this only applicable under my particular vagrant networking configuration:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
```

FWIW, using Draco's answer was pointing me to another IP address, which wasn't working for me.